# Redux share data between states, top level options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm a bit confused on how to communicate between states in React components using Redux.  After some research, it seems that middleware is the answer, but I'd like some top-level clarification on what my options are.

My app is fairly simple, it's a game: the character moves around on the board, an action happens, then the score is updated and a message may be shown.

I have a character component, a scorebar component, and a message component.

The part I am struggling with is how to tell the scorebar (or the message) to update after an event from the character requires the UI to be updated.  I've got reducers working fine, but they're limited to the component state.

Of course, I can dump everything into a global state object, but it feels like there should be a more elegant way to pull this off. What's a recommended architecture for this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using redux for your components states, you should be using `combineReducers` to build a single reducer out of your multiple reducers. If so, you can send actions to your store, and they will be passed to all reducers, so you can react on it appropriately.

Comment: Ahh yes this was it. I was having a "derp" moment and forgot that all reducers received all actions! Thank you!